# where to put <script> tags when using templates for headers / footers

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, templates

In my codeigniter app, I've created a header.php and a footer.php. When I load a view, I do the following in my controller:

```
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

The template.php file looks like this:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

So far, this has been working very well.  However, I'd like to move all my code that loads javascript files from the header to the footer - to help my pages load faster.  Stuff like this is what I'm talking about:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js')?>"></script>
```

The problem is that in the files that make up the "main_content", if I have javascript logic, it no longer works.

For example, let's say I have the following view that acts as the "main_content"

```
    <!-- DISPLAY RESULTS -->
<div class="row-fluid"> 
  <div class="span12 visible-desktop visible-tablet" id="l1locations">
    <table id="switchrecords" name="switchrecords" class="table table-bordered">
    </table>
 </div>

 <div class="span12 visible-phone" id="l1locations">
    <div id="mobileswitchrecords"></div>
</div>              
</div>
    <button class="btn search">Search</button>


 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#search').show();
      $('.search').live('click',function(){
          etc... logic that dynamically fills in the table
 });
 </script>
```

I thought this logic would still work because it's inside the document.ready() and document ready doesn't fire until all files are loaded. 
But I must be wrong because my code no longer works. 
I can include the main jquery include file in the header, and all other js files in the footer.  But any other suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Please note that currently, each view has different inline javascript.  Some pages make a lot of ajax calls, other pages just have simple scripts.  Regardless, for me to move all inline javascript into files is ok, but how does the footer then know which js file to include?  I don't want to include all javascript all the time because the js code only applies to specific pages.

Comment: `I don't want to include all javascript all the time`, Well, I suggest you a method I wrote some months ago to include the external and/or internal JavaScript files within the view (in this case: footer): https://gist.github.com/HashemQolami/5994689

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` is jQuery. You're trying to use jQuery before it's even loaded in, so it'll fail. You can try to move all of your core-JS includes to the bottom of each view file, before the specific view JS, and the footer containing other footer-y stuff. This way, your JS is still loading at the bottom (after the content), and also before your view-specific code.

Comment: yes, that thought crossed my mind.  but i decided to ask anyways because the downside with this solution is that every view file will have the same code to include these files repeated.  maybe there is no other way...

Comment: You shouldn't have inline scripts with your markup, but if you want to continue doing that, you can just have an import of your core JS files, so it's just one line on each view. Or in your footer file, import the current views JS.

Comment: "You shouldn't have inline scripts with your markup," - what are my options for including scripts when using templates?

Comment: @dot Insert the inline JavaScripts into the footer after loading the dependencies. If you couldn't do that with you're template library, put all you're JavaScripts in a file and embed the file into the footer. Once the browser loads the file, it would be stored in the cache.

Comment: @HashemQolami, that would mean the footer would include js files containing my inline js for 'all' views.  or... do you mean that I need to have some conditional statements in the footer that would load the correct js file depending on which view is loaded?  that seems bulky.  maybe I'm missing something or didn't quite understand your comment. Please see my EDIT 1 of post.  Thanks.